# Does the conductivity or resistance change the capacitance value if I use other material for my capacitor plates?

Tags: capacitor

Capacitance depends on surface area. Now I know copper is one of the most conductive materials and is great for capacitors. Steel is so much cheaper though and I can find a plate for the same size much cheaper. Steel is less conductive than copper. Now would that change my capacitance values and lower them? Because secretly I’ve been wanting to use activated carbon which has great surface area but it isn’t even a metal.

Comment: No. Steel will have very little impact on the capacitance. It's a similar "ocean of thermal conduction band electrons." So I can't see a lot of impact there. However, carbon may be a different matter. That is enough of a orders of magnitude difference that calcs may be involved given some specific structure. I've not done those calcs before. So I can't be as strident there.

Comment: The insulating material *between* the plates (dielectric) is quite important to capacitance, though.

Comment: There may be issues with using ferromagnetic materials, but it won't be the capacitance that is affected.

Comment: Why not aluminum, like everyone else? Aluminum is easiest to form into very thin sheets for maximum area.

Comment: If you think about it a charged capacitor has no current flow and therefore resistance is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Without going deep the way Sir @Neil_UK answered your question, my quick answer to your question is:

**No. Changing plate material (thus changing the plate resistance) will not change the Capacitor's capacitance.**

For an Ideal Capacitor, capacitance is governed by 3 factors:

- Dielectric Constant
- Surface Area of one plate
- Distance between the plates

(Note that Permittivity of Free Space is constant)

[image: Ideal Capacitor Formula]

As you can see, the capacitor is not giving care if you changed its plate materials. But again, this is for ideal capacitor only. For real world, you should consider some losses if it is significant to your application. If not, then the formula above is enough to answer question.

Answer (score 3):

Lower conductivity in the plates of a capacitor increases the power losses, without changing the capacitance.

This effect only becomes significant when the operating frequency is high enough that the effective series resistance of the plates becomes significant compared to the impedance of the capacitor.

Using pure metal for the plates, even stainless steel, is unlikely to cause any noticable problem.

Exploiting the high surface area of carbon may cause you loss problems, as to make that large area 'work', you still have to get the plates close together, which usually means a conductive liquid as the other 'plate'. The liquid resistance will appear in series with your capacitor, increasing losses, quite apart from the issue of connecting to your carbon.